# Loop using CountIf for text then moving to next column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have one worksheet (Daily) with data in columns and a header. The data is dynamic based on the number of days in a month and it has been conditionally formatted to icons (Incomplete = T, Complete = R). I'm trying to create a chart on another worksheet (WS2) to show the percent complete and incomplete for each item (header).

I have a table on a 3rd worksheet (WS3) to count all non-empty cells in each column, countif "T", and countif "R". (eg. =COUNTIF(Daily!D5:D29,"R")). The chart on WS1 selects data from WS3 for each item. Sometimes I have to add or delete a column on the Daily page. I'm trying to write a sub to loop through each column on Daily using CountIF and CountA and show the results on WS2.

```
Sub LoopforCt()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Daily As Worksheet
Dim Test As Worksheet
Dim AllData As Variant
Dim pcv As Range

Set Daily = Sheets("Daily")
Set Test = Sheets("Test")
Set AllData = Daily.Range("B5:B100")
Set pcv = Test.Range("A22")

With AllData
 pcv = "=COUNTIF(Daily!C5:C29,""R"")"
End With

End Sub
```

I've been able to get the countif to work for the first column, but I'm lost on how to put this in a loop. I want to continue to CountIf for the next column's results in Test.Range("B22"), etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Should the formula in `B22` be set to `"=COUNTIF(Daily!D5:D29,""R"")"`? You can write a formula with relative references to an entire range, no need to loop column by column.

Comment: Thank you BigBen. Yes, the formula in B22 should be as you wrote. Are you suggesting that I have the formula in Excel not in a macro?

Comment: No, just saying that you don't need to loop through columns - you can write the formula to multiple columns with one line.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking something like this?  pvc.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Daily!R[-17]C:R[15]C,""R"")"  . Would I then add pvc = pvc(0,1)    ?

Comment: `pcv` should be the entire range - not just `A22` but `A22:X22` or whatever column. Then `pcv.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Daily!C5:C29,""R"")"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop.  You can write a formula to a `Range` in one line. You're using relative references, so the `C5:C29` will become `D5:D29`, `E5:E29` as you progress right.

```
Test.Range("A22:X22").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Daily!C5:C29,""R"")" ' replace X with whatever column you need.
```

Or if you prefer to keep `pcv`,

```
Set pcv = Test.Range("A22:X22")
pcv.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Daily!C5:C29,""R"")"
```